# WebScraping & python: Rendering javascript in html?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm trying to build a webcrawler to get the trending stocks from the tsx page.  I currently get all the trending link, now I'm trying to scrape the information  on the individual pages. Based on my code, when I try to output the "quote_wrapper" in the getStockDetails() it returns an empty list. I suspect it's because the JavaScript has not been rendered on the page yet? Not sure if that's a thing. Anyway, I tried to output all the html on the page to debug and I don't see it either. I read that only way to "render" the JavaScript is to use Selenium and use browser.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML"). It worked for the index page so I tried to use it on the others. I also made a comment about it in the code as well. Thanks for your help, if you can.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib2 import urlopen as uReq

import time
import random
import requests


def getTrendingQuotes(source_code):
    # grabs all the trending quotes for that day
    links = []
    page_soup = soup(source_code, "lxml")
    trendingQuotes = page_soup.findAll("div", {"id": "trendingQuotes"})
    all_trendingQuotes = trendingQuotes[0].findAll('a')
    for link in all_trendingQuotes:
        url = link.get('href')
        name = link.text
        # print(name)
        links.append(url)
    return links


def getStockDetails(url, browser):
    print(url)
    source_code = browser.execute_script(
        "return document.documentElement.outerHTML")

    #What is the correct syntax here?
    #I'm trying to get the innerHTML of whole page in selenium driver
    #It seems I can only access the JavaScript for the entire page this way

    # source_code = browser.execute_script(
    #    "return" + url +".documentElement.outerHTML")

    page_soup = soup(source_code, "html.parser")
    # print(page_soup)
    quote_wrapper = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "quoteWrapper"})
    print(quote_wrapper)


def trendingBot(browser):

    while True:
        source_code = browser.execute_script(
            "return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
        trending = getTrendingQuotes(source_code)
        for trend in trending:
            browser.get(trend)
            getStockDetails(trend, browser)
        break
        # print(trend)


def Main():

    url = 'https://www.tmxmoney.com/en/index.html'
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(
        r"C:\Users\austi\OneDrive\Desktop\chromeDriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
    browser.get(url)

    print("[+] Success! Bot Starting!")
    trendingBot(browser)
    browser.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Comment: Is the question about rendering html or rendering javascript? It's not clear what you're looking for.

Comment: Rendering javasScript. I'm trying to access the div element "quoteWrapper" in the getStockDetails. However, it returns an empty list.

Comment: Your class looks wrong. Shouldn't it be quote-wrapper ?

Comment: @QHarr oh wow that works. Do you actually need to pass the url to the function, since it always gets the "quote-wrapper". I don't think so. I'm not quite sure how browser.execute_script(
        "return document.documentElement.outerHTML") works

Comment: What in addition is missing? I am a little unclear what extra info you need now the class name is corrected?

Comment: @QHarr I was just confused. I thought you had to give browser.execute_script( "return document.documentElement.outerHTML") the url for it to go on each specific page.

Comment: No. .get takes you to each page and then using your find method returns the info.

Comment: @QHarr thank you so much for clarifying that for me.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do not mix BeautifulSoup and Selenium its unnecessary. To render page with javascript you need to wait until the element generated, use `WebDriverWait` and get page source with `browser.page_source` but it not used here.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 

def getTrendingQuotes(browser):
    # wait until trending links appear, not really needed only for example
    all_trendingQuotes = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        lambda d: d.find_elements_by_css_selector('#trendingQuotes a')
    ) 
    return [link.get_attribute('href') for link in all_trendingQuotes]

def getStockDetails(url, browser):
    print(url)
    browser.get(url)
    quote_wrapper = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.quote-wrapper')
    print(quote_wrapper.text)
    #print(quote_wrapper.get_attribute('outerHTML'))

def trendingBot(url, browser):
    browser.get(url)
    trending = getTrendingQuotes(browser)
    for trend in trending:
        getStockDetails(trend, browser)

def Main():
    url = 'https://www.tmxmoney.com/en/index.html'
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(
        r"C:\Users\austi\OneDrive\Desktop\chromeDriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
    print("[+] Success! Bot Starting!")
    trendingBot(url, browser)
    browser.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Comment: The answer was great but suggesting `time.sleep()` have killed it all.

Comment: thanks, it just easier method without much typing :D

Comment: @ewwink could you explain what you mean by not mixing Selenium and BeautifulSoup further? and this might be silly, but I'm not sure how to parse the text from the quote-wrapper;  the individual elements in the quote-wrapper. for example: storing the "quote-name" or "quote-price in a variable.

Comment: what BeautifulSoup can do, can be done by selenium and event better because it use real browser for html parser. You can read how to [Locating Elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) and to select child inside `quote-wrapper` use `quote_wrapper.find_element_by_class_name("quote-name" )`